# Passing plots out of a class

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to pass a pyplot Figure out of an external class (as in must be imported), but have been unsuccessful.  I don't even know if this is the way I should be tackling the problem of getting a plot (un-shown) out of a class.

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Plotter(object):
    def __init__(self, xval=None, yval=None):
        self.xval = xval
        self.yval = yval

    def plotthing(self):
        f = Figure(1)
        sp = f.add_subplot(111)
        sp.plot(self.xval, self.yval, 'o-')
        return f
```

So that is the class roughly (names plotfile.py).  Here is the bulk other script.

```
from plotfile import Plotter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app = Plotter(xval=range(0,10), yval=range(0,10))
plot = app.plotthing()
app.show(plot)
```

I have tried several variations on this theme and have tried my best googlefu, but not no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If I am way off on my approach to this I am very open to hearing how to do it correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the app.show(plot) supposed to do?  What does the code really do?  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I just want it to pop up a plot like when you enter `p = plt.plot(xval, yval)` then `plt.show()`.  I just want to do the heavy lifting of setting up the plots in a class so I can call it from various programs.

Comment: Then define a method `show()` that calls `plt.show()`. Currently, your second script calls such a method, but it's nowhere defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few points: I don't think `Figure` works like like you think it does, and your `Plotter` object doesn't have a `.show()` method, so `app.show(plot)` won't work.  The following worked for me:

---

```
# plotfile.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Plotter(object):
    def __init__(self, xval=None, yval=None):
        self.xval = xval
        self.yval = yval

    def plotthing(self):
        f = plt.figure()
        sp = f.add_subplot(111)
        sp.plot(self.xval, self.yval, 'o-')
        return f
```

---

```
from plotfile import Plotter

app = Plotter(xval=range(0,10), yval=range(0,10))
plot = app.plotthing()
plot.show()
raw_input()
```

---

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  I figured it was just some basic misunderstanding, and I was right!  Thanks.